# JWT-based Authorization for API in .NET Core 2: No Unauthorized Error

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-authorization

Well, I am attempting to stand-up JWT-based authorization in my .NET Core 2.x API. I have everything working, save for this: The test action I have set-up to apply authorization is not refusing unauthenticated requests -- it just serves-up the content as if no authorization is applied at all.

**In my `Startup` I have:**

```
    services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
    {
        authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
    {
        jwtOptions.Authority = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
        jwtOptions.SaveToken = true;
        jwtOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build());
    });
```

Then in `Configure`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I have a log-in API action like so:

```
...
    [Route("api/user")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AppUserController : ControllerBase
    {
...
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] LoginDto model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _authenticationHandler.Authenticate(model);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    return Ok(_authenticationHandler.GetJwt(user.Name));
                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt");

            return Ok();
        }
    }
...
```

Where _authenticationHandler is an instance of:

```
public class IdentityHandler
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public IdentityHandler
    (
        IConfiguration configuration,
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager
    )
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public string GetJwt(string username)
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var claims = new HashSet<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.Now.ToString())
        };

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken
        (
            _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], 
            claims: claims,
            signingCredentials: credentials,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)
        );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> Authenticate(LoginDto loginModel)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.Username);
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginModel.Password))
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.NormalizedUserName));
        }

        return identity;
    }
}
```

Finally, I then have an API action annotated with the Authorize directive, such:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
[Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok("accepted");
}
```

And my expectation is that if I attempt to navigate to that action, the request should be refused as unauthorized. It is not. As a total newcomer to JWT, I have no idea what I missed.

I can confirm that my log-in method does indeed work, finding the user and issuing a token which is received back at the client.

Comment: Can you check your request headers what key&values do you have? And also add a breakpoint to the Test action and check what is the value of `User.Identity` is

Comment: Yes, I've done that. The incoming value in the test action for user is null -- i.e., no specific identity at all, just as it should be to test for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer to my own question, after some additional poking-around... in the `ConfigureServices` method of the Startup class, it's necessary to specify the authorization filter to be added to MVC, like so:

```
    services.AddMvc(config =>
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme))
    );
```

That's it. My action with the `[Authorize]` annotation now refuses anonymous requests, as expected.